# How do I resolve this ClassNotFoundexception?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to insert some `documents` into a **MongoDB** database. I have also included the jar file **mongo-java-driver-3.12.7** in my project build path.

My import statements are:

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
```

The error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/DBObject
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3061)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2248)....
```

How do I fix this? Please help me.

**EDIT:** After including the **bson-4.1.0.jar**, **mongodb-driver-core-4.1.0.jar** and **mongodb-driver-3.9.jar** (as I couldn't get the 4.1.0 one), when I run the code, I get an error in all the import statements showing `The package com.mongodb is accessible from more than one module..`.

[image]

Comment: Make sure it should be consider as classpath.

Comment: You need to have it in the class path at runtime as well.

Comment: I have added it both in the `Classpath` and `Modulepath` and tried running it, but I still keep getting this error.

Comment: try adding https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/4.1.0
mongodb-driver-core to the path

Comment: @jagapathi tried it, getting `The import .... cannot be resolved` in all the `import` statements